# Playframework -- where to get working samples

Tags: playframework, sample, playframework-2.3

I decided to try Playframework out. I downloaded play2.3.8 from here https://www.playframework.com/download and noticed that I have 3 activator jars but not a /samples directory. I was able to get a /samples directory out of the play2.2 zip but it doesn't seem to run with the activator jars I got from the play2.3.8 download.

Is there a good place to get samples that work with the latest distribution? To be clear, I am hoping to see an end-to-end app as opposed to the snippets shown in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Play 2.3 you can find tens of samples, tutorials and templates in the Activator's console.

Just in your terminal run `activator ui` command, it will open interactive tool in the browser, it will allow you to create app from chosen template.

Comment: Or run `activator new` to access the templates and samples from the command line. You can also browse the [list of Activator templates here](https://typesafe.com/activator/templates#filter:play).